# If statements failing c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code which is suppose to return Qualify() if credit >= 7 and Salary >= 20000 otherwise return NoQualify, but for some reason it only returns Qualify =/
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabAssignFiveLoanThingy   
{
    public class Loan
    {
        public static void Qualify()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Sorry, at this time you do not meet the requirements for the loan.");
        }

        public static void NoQualify()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You meet the requirements!");
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double Salary;
            int credit;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter your yearly salary:");
            Salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Awesome! please enter your credit rating, on a scale of 1-10:");
            credit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You've entered the following:");
            Console.WriteLine("Salary: {0}\nCredit Rating: {1}", Salary, credit);
            if (Salary < 20000 || credit < 7)      
                Loan.NoQualify();

            if (Salary >= 20000 && credit >= 7)
                Loan.Qualify();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You've swapped the Qualify and NoQualify messages!

Comment: As an aside, it's poor practice to start your class members and local variable names with an upper case. Upper case is generally used for classes. http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html#367

Comment: @Vince's comment is the answer for the question. :D

Comment: @RyPope: This is not Java code.

Comment: @DerekW Standards remain the same.

Comment: @RyPope: Code styling is a convention and not a standard. Furthermore, it depends specifically on the language. For example, all method names in C# start with an upper-case letter by convention. That's a convention that does not translate to Java. See Conventions vs. Standards: http://www.xfront.com/conventions-versus-standards/

Answer (score 3):

The main issue here is that the messages in the `Qualify()` and `NoQualify()` methods are swapped.

They need to be like this:

```
public static void Qualify()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You meet the requirements!");
}

public static void NoQualify()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, at this time you do not meet the requirements for the loan.");
}
```

A secondary issue is that an `if-if` control-flow structure is not really what you are going for. Although it does not change the outcome of your code, it makes the code much more readable in what you are trying to accomplish with an `if-else` control-flow structure.

You are trying to design a system which does not allow for both of those `if` statements to evaluate as true - so why not make it so that can never happen?

```
if (Salary >= 20000 && credit >= 7)
{
    Loan.Qualify();
}
else
{
    Loan.NoQualify();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> if credit >= 7 and Salary >= 20000 otherwise return NoQualify

it seems you need an `if-else` statement:

```
if (Salary >= 20000 && credit >= 7)
    Loan.Qualify();
else
    Loan.NoQualify();
```

Comment: Nope, same problem. When Salary = 10 and Credit = 1 it still returns Qualify()

Comment: @Austen Not possible. Both will be `false` in your case. And `false && false` is `false`.

Comment: @Austen I think your another mistake is you write wrong message in wrong method.As stated in the **comments**

Answer (score 2):

You've swapped the Qualify and NoQualify messages!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Qualify()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You meet the requirements!");
}

public static void NoQualify()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, at this time you do not meet the requirements for the loan.");
}
```